# Can you make the field FirstName on a Person Account record required?

Tags: fields, person-accounts, required-field, required

I need the FirstName field on a Person Account to be required but I can't find how to set it like that. I know you can use a validation rule but I want Salesforce to show the user that it is required before the user tries to save the record.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify some options on default fields, such as `Required`, `Unique` or `External Id`. You can see a Salesforce article on this topic here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385196&type=1

In instances where you can't make the field required at the database level, you can make the field required instead at the Page Layout/Lightning Page level. Keep in mind though that doing this at the page layout level only enforces that requirement for users entering data through the UI - so you should also combine this with a validation rule to enforce the requirement on anyone who loads data via data loader/API or any user who may have a different layout assigned to them where the field is not marked as required.